Can any function in $C^\alpha$ be approximated in $C^{\alpha^-}$ by singular functions?
For every positive $\alpha < 1$, we consider the space $C^{\alpha}$ of Holder continuous functions of order $\alpha$ on $[0, 1]$, equipped with the norm
$$\|f\|_{C^\alpha} := \sup|f| + \sup_{x, y \in [0, 1]} \frac{|f(y) - f(x)|}{|y - x|^\alpha}.$$
We say a non-constant function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ is singular if it is continuous, and in addition differentiable almost everywhere with $f' = 0$ a.e.
Question: For every $f \in C^\alpha$, does there exist a sequence of singular functions $f_n \in C^\alpha$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $C^{\beta}$ for all $\beta < \alpha$?
Comments: The prototypical example of a singular function is the Cantor function, which is Hölder continuous of order $\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$.

If you have convergence in uniform norm and uniform boundedness in $C^\alpha$ the interpolation inequality concludes.

Here is a concrete approximation. Note that there are variants of the Cantor function that are Hölder continuous with exponents arbitrarily close to $1$. Specifically, for $0\le\sigma<1$, consider the unique function $f_\sigma\in C([0,1])$ such that $f_\sigma(0)=0$, $f_\sigma(1)=1$, and
$$f_\sigma(x)=\cases{ \frac12f_\sigma\big(\frac {2x}{1-\sigma} \big)&  if  $0\le x\le \frac{1-\sigma}2$\\ \frac12& if $\frac{1-\sigma}2\le x \le \frac{1+\sigma}2$\\\frac12+\frac12f_\sigma\big(\frac {2x-1-\sigma}{1-\sigma} \big)& if $\frac{1+\sigma}2\le x\le1$}$$
(So in particular $f_{\frac13}$ it is the usual Cantor function, and $f_0$ is the identity function $\rm id$).
One has the following facts:
1). For $0<\sigma<1$ the function $f_\sigma$ is singular, actually a.e. locally constant.
2). $\|f_\sigma-\rm id\|_\infty\le\sigma.$
3). $f_\sigma$ is Hölder of exponent $\alpha_\sigma:=\frac{\log 2}{\log  2-\log({1-\sigma)}}$,  with modulus of continuity $t^{\alpha_\sigma}$.
As a consequence, if
$g\in C^\alpha([0,1]$, the functions $\{g_\sigma:=g\circ f_\sigma\}_{0<\sigma<1}$ are a.e. locally constant  and converge uniformly to $g$ as $\sigma\to0$. Moreover they are eventually (included and) bounded in $C^\gamma([0,1])$, for all $\gamma<\alpha$.
By the compact embedding of $ C^\gamma([0,1])$ in $ C^\beta([0,1])$  for $\beta<\gamma<\alpha$  they also converge to $g$ in  $C^\beta$, for all $\beta<\alpha$.
$$*$$
Details. The function $f_\sigma$ is the unique fixed point of the contraction defined by the RHS of the functional equation. To simplify the description, we may think $f_\sigma(x)$ defined also for $x\ge1$ to be  $f_\sigma(x)=1$: Then $f_\sigma$ is the unique fixed point of the $\frac12$-Lipschitz affine map $T_\sigma:V\to V$ defined on the closed affine space
$V:=\{f\in C_b([0,+\infty)): f(0)=0, f(x)=1 \text{ for all } x\ge1\}\subset C_b([0,+\infty))$ by
$$T_\sigma f (x):=\cases{ \frac12f \big(\frac {2x}{1-\sigma} \big)&  if  $0\le x\le  \frac{1+\sigma}2$\\\frac12+\frac12f \big(\frac {2x-1-\sigma}{1-\sigma} \big)& if $\frac{1+\sigma}2\le x\le1$}.$$
1). If $Z\subset[0,1]$ is the set of points at which $f_\sigma$ is locally constant, we have from the functional equation a disjoint union, $$Z=\frac{1-\sigma}2Z\cup\big(\frac{1-\sigma}2,\frac{1+\sigma}2\big)\cup\big(\frac{1-\sigma}2Z+\frac{1+\sigma}2\big),$$ whence $|Z|=(1-\sigma)|Z|+\sigma$, and $|Z|=1$.
For the other properties it is convenient to introduce the following  non-empty, closed subsets $A, B, C$ of $V$, and check they are $T_\sigma$-invariant sets, so that the fixed point $f_\sigma$ belongs to each of them. The verification is standard  but a bit boring and has to be done by cases (I'll just list the cases I considered).
$$A:=\{f\in V: x-\sigma\le f(x)\le x+\sigma  \text{ for all } 0\le x\le 1\}$$
$$B:=\{f\in V:  f(x)\le x^{\alpha_\sigma}  \text{ for all } x\ge0\}$$
$$C:=\{f\in V:  f \text{ is increasing and sub-additive} \}.$$
Then $f_\sigma\in A$ gives the bound (2), and $f_\sigma\in B\cap C$ gives (3).
Further Details.
To check $T_\sigma(A)\subset A$, consider three cases:
$${\bf (i)\;} x\le\frac{1-\sigma}2,\quad {\bf (ii)\;}\frac{1-\sigma}2 \le x\le\frac{1+\sigma}2,\quad {\bf (iii)\;}\frac{1+\sigma}2\le x.$$
To check $T_\sigma(B)\subset B$, two  cases suffice (the latter  less obvious)
$${\bf (i)\;} x\le\frac{1+\sigma}2,\quad {\bf (ii)\;} \frac{1+\sigma}2\le x.$$
To check $T_\sigma(C)\subset C$, it is clear that $T_\sigma$ maps increasing functions to increasing functions; then to check $T_\sigma(x+y)\le T_\sigma(x)+T_\sigma(y)$ for $f\in C$, consider four cases
$${\bf (i)\;}x+y\le \frac{1+\sigma}2,\quad {\bf (ii)\;}x\le \frac{1+\sigma}2\text{ and }y\ge\frac{1-\sigma}2,\quad{\bf (iii)\;}x\ge y\ge\frac12,$$ $${\bf (iv)\;}x\le \frac{1-\sigma}2,\; y\le \frac{1-\sigma}2,\text{ and } x+y\ge\frac{1+\sigma}2.$$

(In case I'll add details on 1,2,3)

Wow, I did not expect a composition of $g$ with some singular  functions to be an approximating example. Nice! Concerning the steps, I guess $(1)$ just follows from counting the measure of the constant intervals, and $(3)$ follows from oscillation decay. I don’t see immediately how to show $(2)$.

Hm, I guess you can write the maximal difference to the identity as a certain sum, which converges to something less than $\sigma$. So yeah, no need to write out the details if you haven’t yet, I am fine with the derivation as is.

A  clean way to prove these facts on the fixed point of the contraction (call it T) is  by checking that  the sets with  the corresponding properties are non-empty, closed T- invariant  sets.  So the fixed point is in there.

I'm adding some details even for myself, because I'm going to forget everything in short time
